# Error No. 2004. Cant create TCP/IP socket (10106)

Tags: mysql, sockets, tcp

I use XAMPP.
I can connect mysql via admin and phpmyadmin, but when i start to use java and connect to mysql the connection error.
I try to connect via SQLyog and i got these:

Host: localhost
username: root
password: "thepassword"
port: 3306

Error No. 25
Unknown mysql server host 'localhost'(2)

Then, I try to replace localhost with 
Host: 127.0.0.1
username: root
password: "thepassword"
port: 3306

Error No. 2004
Cant create TCP/IP socket (10106)

Here's the class

```
public static Connection getKoneksi(String host, String port, String username, String password, String db ){
    String konString = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + db;
    Connection conn = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(konString, username, password);
        System.out.println("Koneksi berhasil");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  ex.getMessage());
        conn = null;
    }
    return conn;
}
```

How I use it

```
    conn = (com.mysql.jdbc.Connection) dbConn.getKoneksi("127.0.0.1", "3306","gumelarme","passohpass","dbpr");
```

-print stack trace

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:355)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2461)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at Organizer.dbConn.getKoneksi(dbConn.java:22)
at Organizer.PR.<init>(PR.java:24)
at Organizer.PR$5.run(PR.java:254)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:460)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:431)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:305)
... 31 more
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Try killing all other connections to MySQL and then try running the code again.

Comment: @Shaw Mehan: the code work before, i dont know what's happen.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i tried, still same error

Comment: and can you give us what you get with `ex.printStackTrace();`